# Adobe InDesign + third party plugins vs. Framemaker

Tags: adobe-indesign

Apropos of [this posting on Stackoverflow,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371654/application-not-a-markup-language-for-producing-a-user-manual) I'd quite like to hear anyones experiences on using [Adobe InDesign](http://www.adobe.com/products/indesign/?promoid=BPDEI)/[InCopy](http://www.adobe.com/products/incopy/) plus third-party plugins such as [those listed here.](http://www.adobe.com/products/plugins/indesign/)  Specifically, how good would this tool chain be as an alternative to Framemaker for:

- A functional spec document of 2000 pages or so maintained by a team of 4-5 analysts.
- A smaller document of 500 pages mantained by a single analyst or program manager.
- A large technical document of the sort described above incorporating a generated data dictionary (this would be done as a MIF on Framemaker) that is maintained in a CASE tool and imported via a homebrew utility.  Also, specifically maintaining cross-references between this and other parts of the document that are stable across imports.
- A document in multiple volumes with cross-references, TOC and indexes referring to items in different volumes.
- Single-sourcing such a document to PDF, print and HTML or CHF.

Answer (score 4):

I would go for Framemaker.

It has far better support for things like references, indexes and TOC. You can certainly do this in InDesign too but with Framemaker it's a lot easier.

InDesign is made for "creative" documents like magazines, newspapers or books. The main purpose of Framemaker are technical documents like the ones you described.

Comment: I already have Framemaker.  Have you used anything like the tools made by http://www.dtptools.com with InDesign?  I'm trying to gauge how well FM+third party tools works for technical publishing.